# Increase date with one year in Rail 4. undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, increment

I need to store a date in variable: created_date + 1 year. Variable is called decided_at and is `date` type. I wrote this code in my controller:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  @post.statut = 1 
  @post.decided_at = @post.created_at + 1.year // here is the problem
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

It return: `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`

How to repair this?

Comment: Use `@post.decided_at = Time.now + 1.year`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a new method is called, it will initialize to nil.

Try `Time.current + 1.year`

Answer (score 3):

You're building a new post in your controller - but not saving it, therefore it's `created_at` is not yet set.

I'm not sure why you want to add a year to it, but I can suggest either saving it before trying to update it, or perhaps just setting it to the current time + 1 year.